# Comparing Nodes with Collections.sort

Tags: java, sorting, collections, nodes

I got a List with some Tree nodes and want to sort it. As the comparator I use a double variable owned by every node in the List.

Thats my code:

```
List<TreeNode<String>> list = inputNode.getChildren();

for(TreeNode<String> childNode : list)
   {
    Collections.sort(list, childNode.costs);
   }
```

TreeNode is defined like this:

```
public class TreeNode<T> {

public T data;
public double costs;
public List<TreeNode<T>> children;

// Bunch of getters and setters
}
```

What I am try to do is, to sort(descending order) the List of child nodes. I dont want write something new thats already there. So why cant I use `Collections.sort`?

[Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) Isn't `double` a comparable datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it in slightly different way.

Either the TreeNode must implement Comparable http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html or write comparator as anonymous class.

```
 public class TreeNode<T> implements Comparable {

 public T data;
 public double costs;
 public List<TreeNode<T>> children;

 // Bunch of getters and setters

 public int compareTo(TreeNode that) { return (int)(this.cost - that.cost); }
 }
```

or

```
 Collections.sort(ls, new Comparator() 
                       {

                        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) 
                        {
                           //typecast and compare here
                        }
                       }    
                );
```

And, do not call Collections.sort in a loop. One call is sufficient.

Comment: I tried to implement the whole sort in `TreeNode` but didnt worked out. I will use the `compareTo` method. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:
1) make class TreeNode implement Comparable<TreeNode<T>> and implement the compareTo method,
2) Create a Comparator<TreeNode<T>> and use Collections.sort(list, comparator);

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but shouldn't `TreeNode<T>` itself implement Comparable? And then you can compare the values on the node?